# What rare earth metal is used in exhaust pipes?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am an earth scientist, I have a presentation about rare-earth elements. 
I want to get a review of exhaust pipes system. Also, what kind of REE are used in their manufacturing?
I have no knowledge of engine's mechanics or automobile parts, so let's avoid technical jargon :p.

Comment: Perhaps you mean in the [Catalytic converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalytic_converter)?. The pipes themselves are usually pretty standard metals (stainless steel, etc).

Comment: I just want to know if they are used as alloys or something like that!
Since I don't own a vehicle, and I'm not mechanical engineer, Idk anything about engines or motor vehicles.

Comment: Why have you picked exhaust pipes in particular? Please do [edit] your question to add a bit more information about what it is you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

**Cerium or Ce**

Cerium is a silvery-white metal that easily oxidizes in the air. It is the most abundant of the rare earth elements and has many uses. For instance, cerium oxide is used as a catalyst in catalytic converters in automotive exhaust systems to reduce emissions, and is highly desirable for precision glass polishing. Cerium can also be used in iron, magnesium and aluminum alloys, magnets, certain types of electrodes, and carbon-arc lighting.

Comment: What other REE can be used?

Comment: @user10036 
[The three-way catalyst includes a honeycombed carrier base made of, for example, cordierite or a metal foil, a catalyst-carrying layer made of, for example, active alumina powders or silica powders and coated on the surface of the carrier base, and a precious metal such as platinum carried on the catalyst-carrying layer.] 
[...]
[An oxidation catalyst is also known, in which a precious metal is carried on a catalyst-carrying layer made of zeolite, which has excellent in absorption characteristics for HC contained in the exhaust gas.]

(https://www.google.ca/patents/US8225601)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of an exhaust system is usually made from steel or stainless steel (which gives better corrosion resistance for increased cost). Mild steel parts may be plated with chrome (especially if they are visible eg in motorcycles) or coated with aluminium to manage corrosion.

The exhaust system may also include catalytic converters and/or particle filters which may incorporate more exotic materials depending on the technology used.

Catalytic converters are generally focused on educing emissions of nitrogen compounds (NOX), metal catalysts, especially platinum are commonly used, although this is an area of ongoing research and development, especially to find cheaper and more easily available catalysts as a catalytic converter can now represent a significant fraction of the cost of a car.

Diesel engines in particular also use physical filter to reduce emissions of very fine particulates which contribute to smog and are hazardous to human health, especially in urban areas with high traffic. These are often made from ceramic fibres of matrices and need to be able to tolerate temperatures high enough to burn off accumulated soot. So these engineering ceramics are quite a likely use of rare earth metals.

Comment: Well, there is quite a bunch of REE out there, until now I'm sure of Y, Sc, Ce...

Comment: you are an earth scientist about to give a talk on rare earths, and what you know so far is there is quite a bunch of them (three at least) ??